# Cannot import contacts from SIM card on Prestigio MultiPhone

Tags: contacts, sim-card, import

I'm using Prestigio MultiPhone 3504 Muze running on Android 5.0.2 Lollipop. I can't seem to import contacts from the SIM card.

When I go to `Contacts -> Menu`, I got the next options:

1. `Call History`
2. `New Contact`
3. `Settings`

Why I don't see `Import from SIM card` option? Where is it?

Comment: Are you in the Phone app because I can definitely see the Import from SIM card option in Contacts app? See images here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eYu7w.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/NTpdP.png Also, why would the Contacts app be showing "Call history"! Which Android device are you using?

Comment: @Firelord I'm using `Prestigio MultiPhone 3504 Muze`. Finally I notice that it hasn't that tab at all, vut automatically import all contacts from SIM card. My broblem was that I haven't got contacts on SIM card.

Comment: I can confirm that my Android 5.0.2 has Import from sim card option in the contacts application.

Comment: @Lucky I believe you, but the problem is it's absent in my phone) I think the problem is solved, since all SIM card contacts were imported automatically after I download contacts onto SIM card

Comment: @VB_ it's been a while, but it seems you found the cause (and the fact that manufacturers can customize their stock apps, so they may behave differently compared to other devices) and solution by yourself, which is great! Could you post it as a proper answer?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Prestigio MultiPhone 3504 Muze. Finally I notice that it hasn't that tab at all, vut automatically import all contacts from SIM card. My broblem was that I haven't got contacts on SIM card.

> See images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYu7w.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTpdP.png

It may be the case, contacts from SIM cards are imported only once, so the above menu fails to open, once contacts got imported.

But you can easily test the above, selecting "Add New Contact" and saving it on your SIM card.

That way you can try to open "Import contacts from SIM card" menu again, not removing and reinserting the SIM card again.